# How to get from Istanbul to Ankara by land?

Tags: trains, istanbul, ankara

How can I travel from Istanbul (which station, and by what means) to Ankara? I am looking for a bit more details than general track, as in what website can I use to book the tickets, and whether all days are open for travel. I tried the official websites, but **I do not know which stations I should be targeting**, and I could not get results. (seat61 website has **outdated informatio**n as it looks, as in not up to 2018, thus the information is NOT ACCURATE!).

http://www.tcddtasimacilik.gov.tr/
what stations?

https://www.metro.istanbul/en
does this even work?

Comment: I think you need to specify precisely why the information on seat 61 does not work for you as the link provided there allows me to search from trains from Istanbul to Ankara and presumably book them too although I did not try it.

Comment: Rome2Rio.com — won't show all possibilities, and will probably have the costs wrong, but usually has links to air/train/bus websites.

Comment: as i said, seat61 has outdated information (it has not been updated beyond 2016)

Comment: @WGroleau https://www.rome2rio.com/ is an excellent website, thank you, at least I can get the station names

Comment: I'm reading this question trying to get an answer, when I finally realized I was the original poster! We came a full circle :) The answer is: tcdd website has an app, I used the app to book, and just communicated with sign language with bus drivers to get to the right station

Answer (score 1):

As pointed to by WGroleau and your use of [Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Istanbul/Ankara), from Istanbul to Ankara, a distance of some 260 miles/420 km, returned a number of bus, train, and combinations, all taking some 6-7 hours and costs ranging from $12-20 (from ₺ 60-95).

- Train/bus/train: Aksaray by M1 train to Otogar, change stations to Istanbul Otogari for bus to Gebze for YHT to Ankara
- Bus MetroTurizm
- Bus, train via Pendi̇k YHT İstasyonu
  , M2 train at Vezneciler to Sisli-Mecidiyeköy, walking to Mercidiyekoy station for the 251 bus to Pendi̇k YHT İstasyonu, changing to Pendik station for the YHT train to Ankara
- Bus Kamil Koc, taking the M1 train from Aksaray to Otogar, changing to Istanbul Otogari for bus via Umraniye to Ankara

[Rome2Rio.com](https://www.rome2rio.com/) search results expand to detail station names, map locations, departure times, costs, and include links to transportation providers (train, bus, cab, rideshare etc.).